# Issue with validation of XML Identity Constraints with .NET?

Tags: .net, xml, validation

I have the following Schema I was using for testing validation behavior (using it with XMLDocument alongside a simple xml file that matched the schema):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="testSchema.xsd" targetNamespace="testSchema.xsd">

  <xs:element name="multiEle" type="typeOne">
    <xs:key name="keyOne">
      <xs:selector xpath="./eleOne" />
      <xs:field xpath="@boolTwo" />
    </xs:key>
  </xs:element>

  <xs:complexType name ="typeOne">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="eleOne" type="xs:string"/>

      <xs:sequence>

        <xs:element name="eleTwo" type="xs:decimal" />

        <xs:element name="eleThree">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:simpleContent>
              <xs:extension base="xs:boolean">
                <xs:attribute name="boolTwo" />
              </xs:extension>
            </xs:simpleContent>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>      

      </xs:sequence>      

      <xs:element name ="eleFour">        
        <xs:complexType>
          <xs:sequence>

            <xs:element name="eleOne">
              <xs:complexType>
                <xs:sequence>
                  <xs:element name="eleFive" />
                </xs:sequence>
              </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>

            <xs:element name="eleSix" />    

          </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
      </xs:element>

      <xs:choice>
        <xs:element name="eleOne" type="xs:string"/>
        <xs:element name="eleTwo" type="xs:decimal" />
      </xs:choice>

    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

I expected this schema to not even compile, let alone validate, as the identity constraint pointed to an attribute on an element where such an attribute did not exist. Furthermore, no attribute was specified in the XML document, which was this:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<multiEle xmlns="testSchema.xsd">
  <eleOne>eleOne1</eleOne>
  <eleTwo>2</eleTwo>
  <eleThree boolTwo="anySimpleType">true</eleThree>
  <eleFour>
    <eleOne>
      <eleFive></eleFive>
    </eleOne>
    <eleSix>anyType</eleSix>
  </eleFour>
  <eleOne>abc</eleOne>
</multiEle>
```

However, I found that the schema compiled and that the XMLdocument validated without throwing any exceptions (specified null for the handler). Is there something that I am missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `xs:selector` does not select any elements: it is looking for `elemOne` elements in no namespace, but your `elemOne` elements are in namespace `testSchema.xsd`. An empty set can't contain two elements with the same key value, so your instances are valid.

If you validate using Saxon 9.6, it gives you a warning at schema compile time:

```
Warning: on line 5 of test.xsd:
  The complex type typeOne does not allow a child element named eleOne
```

(Saxon 9.7 isn't producing this warning - I'm investigating why.)

The XSD specification doesn't make it an error to use an XPath expression that always selects an empty sequence. That's because specifying this is pretty complex - it would require all the machinery of the XQuery Formal Semantics specification to define the static typing rules. Saxon does it by riding on the back of its schema-aware XPath processing, which does this analysis (according to its own rules, not any W3C rules).

Comment: I forgot all about needing to specify namespaces in the XPath query, that's what I was missing. It failed properly once I corrected the lack of namespace, thank you!